# Creating lines from aspect value

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, aspect

I have a shapefile that contains multiple agricultural stand information. One of the columns is the mean aspect value of the stands. I need to draw lines using the mean aspect value of the stands. Is it possible to do it in ArcGIS pro?

Comment: Draw them manually or automatically? How many stands? Can you add a drawing of how it should look like? Do you want the lines only for visualization purposes or create a new line layer?

Comment: I have 140 stands in a shapefile and I want them to be drawn automatically. I only want them for visualization purposes.